# In Xcode Can I read plist values in .xcconfig file

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, xcconfig

I have my project plist file and in it there are some default key-values and some custom key-values.

Now I created my appconfig.xcconfig file and I would like to know if I can obtain the value according to some key in the plist file?

So for example, I added a key-value pair in the plist like this:

```
<key>custom_key</key><value>custom_string</value>
```

Now in my xcconfig file, how can I get the `custom_string`? Is it able to do that in Xcode?

Comment: you can read value from xcconfig to plist using 
$(custom_key)

Comment: @a.masri have you tried this, is it working? Since I tried and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yes it's working i'm sure

Comment: how to you add xcconfig in to your project ?

Comment: @a.masri, thanks for replying, I added it in Info -> Configurations -> Debug/Release -> myxcconfig

Comment: @a.masri I can set values from the same .xcconfig to plist but cannot read from plist.

Comment: I've done a quick example to see him . 
https://github.com/ahmedAlmasri/XConfig

Comment: @a.masri, thanks for doing this, I have read your example, and I think you misunderstand me here, what you did in the example is set the value to plist in the xcconfig file, in other words, you are reading values from xcconfig to plist. But I want the exact opposite thing: xcconfig to read plist value.

Comment: You want read plist value in xcconfig  ??

Comment: @a.masri, that's what I asked for...

Comment: I do not know why you need to do this but I have a solution you can using run script 
for example 

read bundle id `BUNDLE_ID=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleIdentifier" "${BUILD_ROOT}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}")`

write in xcconfig  `echo "BUNDLE = $BUNDLE_ID" >> test.xcconfig`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168707/discussion-between-boris-and-a-masri).

Answer (score 0):

If you need read xcconfig value into plist, you can use:

```
$(KEY_NAME)
```

If you need read plist value info xcconfig, you can use run script, as follows:

1- Go to targets and select your target.

2- Select build phases.

3- Click on add -> select new run script phase.

4- Add this command for example:

```
BUNDLE_ID=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleIdentifier" "${BUILD_ROOT}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}") 

echo "BUNDLE = $BUNDLE_ID" >> BUILDROOT/NAME.xcconfig
```

5- Build your project (<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>).

6- Open your xcconfig you will find the value has been added.